# Unable to display relations data from eloquent relationship

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to display in my view data from an eloquent relationship but i seem to be doing a tiny bit wrong. dd shows the relation in the collection but i just can't call the data correctly in my view. Below is what i have done

Employee model

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Task model

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
}
```

TaskController

```
public function index()
{
    $alltask = Task::with('employee')->get();

    dd($alltask);

    /*return view('task.task', compact('alltask', 'empwithtask'));*/
}
```

task view

```
@foreach ($alltask as $task)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $task->priority }}</td>
    <td>{{ $task->firstname }}</td> 
    /* this is meant to be the  employee.firstname */
    <td>{{ $task->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $task->begin }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I'm not able to display $task->firstname, firstname is from the employees table. Below is a snapshot of the result of dd

[image: dd capture]

How do I show the employee firstname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$task->employee->firstname
```

Comment: That fixed it. Beating myself up now for not trying it this way over the weekend. Thanks